# Having trouble defining httpResponse in callback function

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using a promise to create httpRequest functions for every instance of `matchCenterItem`, push them in an array, then run them in a row. What I want to do is collect the httpResponse of every one of these functions, and push them to the `ebayPingResults` array. When I run this, I get an error stating the following:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at collectEbayResults (main.js:444:57)
    at null.<anonymous> (main.js:450:15)
    at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
    at c.extend.then (Parse.js:2:5447)
    at main.js:439:40
    at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
    at Parse.js:2:4651
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:665)
    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:4602)
```

The line it's referring to is this:
`var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);`

Here's the full code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {

    //defines which parse class to iterate through
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    var promises = [];
    //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
    query.limit(10);
    query.find().then(function(results) {

      for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
          console.log(results[i].get('searchTerm'))

          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
            //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
          promises.push(function() {
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
              url: url,
              params: {
                'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
                'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
                'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
                'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
                'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
                'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
                'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
                'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
                'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
                //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
                'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
                'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
              }
            });
          });
      }
      console.log(promises);

      Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(results){

        var ebayPingResults = [];

        function collectEbayResults (httpResponse){
          var httpresponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          ebayPingResults.push(httpresponse);
        }

        for (i=0; i<promises.length; i++)
          {
            collectEbayResults(httpresponse);
          }

        console.log(ebayPingResults);
        response.success(
          {
            "Top 3": ebayPingResults
          }
        );

      }, function(err) {
          console.log('error!');
          response.error('DAMN IT MAN');
          });
    });
});
```

I've written a previous function that referenced httpResponse in this way for a success function, and it worked fine, not sure why it's not working in this case.

Comment: you aren't passing in anything to collectEbayResults...

Comment: @Fosco when I try passing in `httpresponse`, it says it's not defined.

Comment: try passing in results[i]

Comment: Same error. The act of trying to define httpresponse as the JSON parsing of the response from the httprequest is what seems to be tripping it up.

Comment: console.log all the things!